# Extracting certain file from large tar ball taking forever

Tags: linux, extract, tar

I have a VERY large "tar.gz" archive (~50 GB) and I'm wondering if it's possible for tar to skip processing N number of bytes or something of that sort, or at least make tar begin reading the file from the end instead reading it from the beginning.

Of course i can do `tar xvf archive.tar.gz path/to/file` but this command will take forever, so i was hoping to find a quicker way to go about it.

Thanks.

Comment: No, tar does not have such an option

Comment: Not a solution but something helpful is to do specific extraction based on particular file name or with regex. Refer: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-extracting-specific-files/